EF Core: how to make owned collection required?
I have the following entities:
public class Cart
{
    public required Guid Id { get; init; }
    public required List<CartProduct> Products { get; init; }
}

public class CartProduct
{
    public required Guid ProductId { get; init; }
    public required int Quantity { get; set; }
}

I'm configuring the Cart entity as follows:
public class CartEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Cart>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Cart> cartEntity)
    {
        cartEntity.ToTable("carts");

        cartEntity
            .HasKey(cart => cart.Id)
            .HasName("pk_carts");

        cartEntity
            .Property(cart => cart.Id)
            .HasColumnName("id");

        cartEntity.OwnsMany(
            cart => cart.Products,
            products => products.ToJson("products")
        );
    }
}

But it results in the "products" property considered nullable.
Here's a code snippet from generated migration:
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "carts",
    columns: table => new
    {
        id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: false),
        products = table.Column<string>(type: "jsonb", nullable: true)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("pk_carts", x => x.id);
    }
);

Notice how the products column is marked with nullable: true.
I've tried the following two options:
cartEntity.OwnsMany(
    cart => cart.Products,
    products => products.ToJson("products")
);

cartEntity
    .Navigation(cart => cart.Products)
    .IsRequired();

and
cartEntity
    .OwnsMany(
        cart => cart.Products,
        products => products.ToJson("products")
    )
    .Navigation(cart => cart.Products)
    .IsRequired();

But with both approaches I'm getting the same error:

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception ''Cart.Products' cannot be configured as required since it was configured as a collection.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Is there a way to make this property not-nullable?
PS: yes, I could just go and edit the generated migration, but I would like to have a way to configure this using Fluent API.

You couldn't edit the migration either. There's no way to make a collection of entities required in a relational database, because an rdbms can't enforce a 1:1-n relationship. That would mean that parent and child records must be inserted in one atomic statement. SQL doesn't have syntax for that.

I do not believe it is possible to configure an owned collection as required. Just be sure to declare your owned collection with a default value:
public List<Entity> Entities { get; set; } = [];

That way if a null is stored in the database (such as through adding the field in a migration), when you select it through EF core, it will be a blank collection instead of a null.
The reasoning for this has to do with the idea of 'required collections' not being enforceable in relational databases other than through business logic. While it would seem feasible that an owned collection's nullability could theoretically be enforced, EF core does not support it.
